# Best practice for alternating background colors on table rows

Tags: html, css, colors

I'm working on styling several tables with rows of data across a single line.  Each row should be readable across the width of the table, so I will be adding a light background color to alternating rows.

Is there a "best practice" for deciding whether the first row of the table should have a **white** or **color** background?

Comment: I don't believe it matters; though I'd suggest clearly marking the first row of the `<table>` with a colour that's distinct from the background colour of the element enclosing the `<table>` in order to clearly distinguish it. But that's purely opinion, rather than a 'best practice' of any kind. And, as noted, [ux.se] is probably more appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: Clarification needed on the comment by @3boll

Comment: This is a User Experiece question, Stack Exchange has a site where you will get better answers. ux.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thank you. Got an answer below, will utilize ux in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as best practice, the first row should contrast with the table header colour. As far as code goes:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script TYPE="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
 zebraRows('tbody tr:odd td', 'odd');
});
 
//used to apply alternating row styles
function zebraRows(selector, className)
{
  $(selector).removeClass(className).addClass(className);
}
  
// Tweak as required
$(function(){
 $("table").css("width", "80%");
 $("th").css("text-align", "left");
 $(".index").css("width", "50px");
 $(".u_date").css("width", "150px");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wouldn't a white or light yellow background equally contrast with a black background header?

Comment: At that point choose the greater contrast; white.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is `:nth-child` css selector!

As for colors you can't go wrong with something light light gray as a background. Similar to what this site does with the code snippets.

Apply a class to your table and use it like so..

```css
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table th, .table tr, .table td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}
.table td {
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">    
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Cool</td>
        <td>Here</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Cool</td>
        <td>Here</td>
    </tr>    
    <tr>
        <td>Something</td>
        <td>Cool</td>
        <td>Here</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Edit

Edited my snippet to better reflect the question.

Comment: This isnt answer the ops question

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child(even) or nth-child(odd), check out my [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogBEQx).

Example

```
td:nth-child(even) {
  background:#d7d7d7;
}
```

Comment: This does not address the question asked.  Thanks.